# How to fetch all the member property details on rendering rvt 3d modal

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am working on Forge Viewer. Rendering a 3D modal based on URNSourceFile.

Problem Statement :

We have a scenario to fetch all the member properties information in JSON format.
On loading 3D modal we have to fetch the member details and bind it to table.

Use Case : All the member information needs to be loaded in table(not from the forge viewer).
Please provide the solution to fetch the member property details on loading 3D modal.

Please find the attached screenshot for the reference
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8xqX.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get properties via calling [GET Properties](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/) before loading the model, but I would advise you don't fetch all properties at once. It would cause your web browser crash after loading heavy data.